# How to vertically center object bigger than its parent?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve like this example:
[image: Example]

I know how to do it by using background-image in css but I dont want to do it as the object could be anything. It could be img, svg, canvas, or even a div. Is there any other solutions?

Comment: photo won't open

Comment: Even though it's closed (duplicate), the solutions below, especially the one using flex, are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 100px 0;
}

.hoder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.center{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="hoder">
        <div class="center">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very good solution using flex box. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote years ago how to do exactly that:

https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/DpmnK

```css
.box{
  position:absolute;  /* or relative */
  /* assume box has height limit lower than the image height */
  height: 100px;
  /* demo-related styles: */
  margin: auto;
  top:0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}

/* The magic: */
.box > img{
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150/FF0000" />
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably mention that this is SCSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use object-fit property of img, much cleaner solution.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
  object-fit: cover:
}
```

Read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: black;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

.img {
  height: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div class="parent">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming parent has non static position, you can do something like this:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}

.big-img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="big-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558980394-34764db076b4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
</div>
```

Explanation:
What you are doing is placing the top-left corner of the child image 50% below the top and 50% to the right of the top-left corner of the parent container. You then have to transform the child image to translate it's position to the actual center of the parent container

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mNpjJa